# Time Complexity of Ternary Search Algorithm

Tags: search, time, complexity-theory

I have an assignment that wants me to write an ternary search algorithm and compute its time complexity afterwards. I was able to write an algorithm for it but I couldn't come up with any ideas how to compute its complexity. I think I didn't understand the concept of big-theta notation.

Here is my code: It works like binary search but only divides the list into there pieces and continues the search like that.

```
    *some list which contains n increasingly-ordered integers;*

    int num;

    int min = 1;
    int max = n;

    int middle1 = (2*min+max)/3; 
    int middle2 = (min+2*max)/3;

    cin >> num;    //num is the number that is wanted to be found

    while (middle1 != middle2)
    {
        middle1 = (2*min+max)/3;
        middle2 = (min+2*max)/3;

        if(num <= list[middle1])
            max = middle1;
        else if(num >list[middle1] && num <= list[middle2])
            {
                    min= middle1; 
                    max = middle2;
            }
        else
            min = middle2;
    }
    if(num == list[max])
        cout << "your number is found in the "<< max <<"th location\n";
    else
        cout << "number cannot be found";
```

If you could explain how to determine its complexity in terms of big-theta notation, it would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At each step, you are reducing the size of the searchable range by a constant factor (in this case 3). If you find your element after *n* steps, then the searchable range has size *N* = 3<sup>*n*</sup>. Inversely, the number of steps that you need until you find the element is the logarithm of the size of the collection. That is, the runtime is O(log *N*). A little further thought shows that you can also always construct situations where you need all those steps, so the worst-case runtime is actually Θ(log *N*).

Comment: Shouldn't it be less efficient than the binary search since as the n in n-ary search goes to the size of the list, it becomes the linear search?

Comment: We're only talking about the asymptotics here. Changing the value of `n` just multiplies the time by some constant.

Comment: I must pay more attention to these in the lesson I think, there are lots of unanswered questions in my mind. But thank you, your explanation helped me to answer the question.

Comment: @MertToka: Here's an analogy: Consider the number of digits you need to write down an integer in place-value notation. The number of digits is logarithmic in the value of the number. The actual number of digits depends on the number base, but for different bases, the number of digits differs only by a constant multiple.

Answer (score 3):

It is Θ(log3(N)).
To check how to calculate complexity just check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

To read more about ternary search, just check the wikipedia page also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

Comment: Which can (and should) be written O(log(N)).

Comment: How did you come up with that answer? And did you mean Big-Theta(which I can't type in keyboard) by typing O statement?

Comment: @MertToka: You can type `&Theta;` into the post; HTML entity references are accepted.

Comment: You helped me a bit but I have already checked those links beforehand I ask a question to here. But thanks.