# What is the time complexity of below algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

Given a sorted array, determine if it contains a given number x:
Instead of using binary search i.e. dividing array into two parts.
If I divide the array into **three parts** and recursively find the element in these three parts. So what would be the **time complexity** or the **order**(in terms of size n of the array) of this algorithm

Comment: lets we remove C++ and Java tags it is not related to language..

Comment: Why are you posting the same question again? You should paste the code to get the right answer.

Comment: @notsogeek Did you read m-way tree?? and do you have any idea why binary seach dome in `log2(n)`.

Comment: Do you mean m-ary tree ? If yes but than I am not able to figure out the worst case complexity.

Comment: Read from wiki: [Ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search)  and [Time Complexity of Ternary Search Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861819/time-complexity-of-ternary-search-algorithm)

Comment: Just to confirm would the worst case be n^(log 2 to the base 3) = 2 ^log(n to the base 3) ?

Comment: So would the time comp. T(n)=2*T(n/3)+c or T(n)=T(2*n/3)+c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity will be the same as binary search.

The original binary search consist of two phases. First a constant number of steps onto the original array, then a recursive call on a array of half size. Thus complexity can be expressed as

```
T(n) = C1 + T(n/2)
```

If you divide in three parts, you perform more comparisons and conditional tests, but still a constant time operation on the array of size n, then you call recursively on a array of size n/3. Which means

```
T(n) = C2 + T(N/3)
```

Both functions evaluate to `Theta(log n)`.

You can generalize. What if i divide in `k` parts. The complexity is

```
f(n) = Ck + f(n/k)
```

which result in

```
f(n) = Ck log(n)/log(k) + Dk
```

As k increases, you get a bigger logerithm divisor, but the constants Ck and Dk also increases, as you perform more operations before jumping into the sub array. Think about the case where `n=k`

Comment: And what would be the worst case

Comment: So is Ck proportional to k ?

Comment: yes it is. Think about how many comparisons in binary search compared to the one of your exercise.write the pseudocode, it will help

Comment: So hence would binary Search be more fast than search which divide array into k (k>2) parts ?

Comment: its better to code and compare.

Comment: After cutting the array into k parts, you can use binary search to find which part to recurse into, so Dk can be log_2(k).